# Get list of keys based on a value when there are multiple values per key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How does one get a list of keys based on a value when there are multiple values per key?

The code below can get a list when the value is a single object. However it fails to get the keys when there are multiple objects as values or when there is additional data in the value.

```
mydict = {
    'romeo': 16,
    'juliette': 16,
    'zena': 'red', 
    'gabby': 'red', 
    'lauren': 'smart',
    'betty': 'smart',
    'kristen': 'sweet',
    'lisa': 'sweet',
    'lucy': ['smart', 'sweet'],
    'shawna': 'green field', 
    'terry' : 'the green field is on fire', 
    'dorothy': 'shelly plays on the green field',
    'jenny': ['intelligent', 'cuts the smart green field grass'], 
}

needle = 'green field'
filtered_keys = [k for k, v in mydict.items() if v == needle]
print(filtered_keys)
```

When `needle = 16`, the output is correct: `['romeo', 'juliette']`.

When `needle = 'red'`, the output is correct: `['zena', 'gabby']`.

When `needle = 'smart'`, the output is *incorrect*: `['lauren', 'betty']`.
The expected output is `['lauren', 'betty', 'lucy', 'jenny']`.

When `needle = 'sweet'`, the output is *incorrect*: `['kristen', 'lisa']`.
The expected output is `['kristen', 'lisa', 'lucy']`.

When `needle = 'green field'`, the output is *incorrect*: `['shawna']`
The expected output is `['shawna', 'terry', 'dorothy', 'jenny']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer does not handle the case when `needle` is `in` a string that is `in` a list. That is, the other answer only handles when `needle` is equal to the value or directly contained by the value. Thus, the other solution does not work when, say, `needle = 'green field'` as per the test cases included in your question.

To generalize, you can recursively check if the value contains `needle`.

```
from typing import Any
from typing import Dict
from typing import Iterable

def keys_containing_value(d: Dict, needle: Any):
    def recursively_in(x: Any, n: Any):
        if isinstance(x, str) and isinstance(n, str):
            return n in x
        if type(x) is type(n):
            return x == n
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):
            return any(recursively_in(item, n) for item in x)
    return [k for k, v in d.items() if recursively_in(v, needle)]
```

And here's how the function works using your data and test cases:

```
mydict = {
    'romeo': 16,
    'juliette': 16,
    'zena': 'red',
    'gabby': 'red',
    'lauren': 'smart',
    'betty': 'smart',
    'kristen': 'sweet',
    'lisa': 'sweet',
    'lucy': ['smart', 'sweet'],
    'shawna': 'green field',
    'terry': 'the green field is on fire',
    'dorothy': 'shelly plays on the green field',
    'jenny': ['intelligent', 'cuts the smart green field grass'],
}
needles = [
    16,
    'red',
    'smart',
    'sweet',
    'green field',
]

for needle in needles:
    print(keys_containing_value(mydict, needle))
```

**Output:**

```
['romeo', 'juliette']
['zena', 'gabby']
['lauren', 'betty', 'lucy', 'jenny']
['kristen', 'lisa', 'lucy']
['shawna', 'terry', 'dorothy', 'jenny']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. I would initially recommend that you just wrap all your `dict` values in a list. So your `dict` would be:

```
mydict = {'romeo':[16],
    'juliette':[16],
    'zena': ['red'], 
    'gabby': ['red'], 
    'lauren': ['smart'],
    'betty': ['smart'],
    'kristen': ['sweet'],
    'lisa': ['sweet'],
    'lucy': ['smart', 'sweet'],
    'shawna': ['green field'], 
    'terry' :['the green field is on fire'], 
    'dorothy' :['shelly plays on the green field'],
    'jenny': ['intelligent', 'cuts the smart green field grass'], 
    }
```

And then your list comprehension would look like this:

```
list_keys = [key for key, val in mydict.items() if lvalue in val]
```

Another option is to test for what type the value in the `dict` is. I don't recommend this, but if your situation doesn't permit the previous solution, this will likely work. So your list comprehension would look like this:

```
list_keys = [key for key, val in mydict.items() if (type(val)==list and lvalue in val) or lvalue==val]
```

The problem here is that if your `dict` values ever get other kinds of iterable, then you'll have to change your code to check for those other iterable types. Just checking whether the value is an iterable won't work, because then when you check a `string` against the value, you'll run into other problems. Things like `'green' in 'green sleeves'` evaluating to `True` even though (based on what you've shown in your question), I think you would want that to evaluate to `False`.

Comment: The asker does want `'green' in 'green sleeves'` evaluated to True (see her example with terry)